# Self-Study and Proof-Assistant Software

Tags: solution-verification, self-learning

I'm not sure if this is a right question to ask or correct platform to ask. But still putting it here in case it's right thing to do. If not, please let me know I'll delete the question.

I just came across theorem-prover programming language, Lean. I'm still studying about it, so don't know complete details about it. My understanding is, it helps in confirming if the theorem proof is correct or not.

If that's true can we use it during solving proof problems during self-study? The biggest problem I face during self-studying math is I'm not always very sure if the proof answer I wrote is correct or not. Solutions from manuals or other sources not always helpful as the method I took might not be the same as given in the solution. And since we are doing self-study, getting help from other is not always possible. So, Lean kind of things might be very useful. I can write the proof in Lean & Lean can tell me if it's correct or not.

So, is Lean (or some other similar language) help in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in theory. But in 2021 it still takes quite a bit of skill and effort to formalise anything at all in, say, Lean, so it might not be the most effective use of your time in practice. If you've got no deadlines, give it a go!

Comment: I think trying to prove things using a proof assistant will help you to understand how to write good proofs. I don't know what subjects you are studying, but it will help to start by looking at subjects like the algebra of the usual number systems and the calculus that are already well supported by Lean (or whatever other proof assistant takes your fancy).

Comment: Thanks both of you! This is encouraging. I mainly study linear algebra, real analysis, topology, etc. Not too advance maths. Hope Lean (or other) have decent support of these topics.

Comment: @Beta I was basically asking myself the same question. Did you give this approach of using/learning Lean while practicing proofs a try? How was your experience?

Comment: @JessicaNowak: Sorry, I realized that checking proof oneself or by others is much more useful and easy than learning a programming language. So, I didn't pursued this line. But you can.

Comment: As someone who has developed his own proof assistant, I think they are a good way to learn the basic methods of proof, e.g. structuring a proof, manipulating quantifiers, etc. But it probably won't get you very far in studying the informal proofs typically found in, say, textbooks on real analysis.

Comment: ... They might be useful as a kind of calculator to manipulate the terms of a complicated statement or definition, e.g. given the definition of a continuous function, determine the definition of a discontinuous function.